# Return Value to Python script from shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python

I'm trying to return a string from shell script to python getting the below error.

```
./whiptail.sh: 10: return: Illegal number: uuiiu
```

i tried running the whiptail command within python directly using subprocess.Popen even at that point im not able to read the user input from python..  If anyone tried this please let me know how to solve this issue.

shell script snippet

```
#!/bin/sh


COLOR=$(whiptail --inputbox "What is your favorite Color?" 8 78 Blue --title "Example Dialog" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
                                                                        # A trick to swap stdout and stderr.
# Again, you can pack this inside if, but it seems really long for some 80-col terminal users.
exitstatus=$?
if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
    echo "User selected Ok and entered " $COLOR
    return $COLOR
else
    echo "User selected Cancel."
fi

echo "(Exit status was $exitstatus)"
```

Comment: welcome aboard! =) Could you please add code formatting to make it more readable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within `sh` which is actually `dash` on Ubuntu the builtin command `return` can returns only numerical values - exit statuses, which have a meaning in a context of a function or sourced script. Source [`man sh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dash.1.html):

> The syntax of the return command is
>
> ```
> return [exitstatus]
> ```

Everything other with your shell script looks correct. I think you need to use `echo $COLOR` instead *return* and suppress other echo-es.

In case you need to return more data to the main script you can output everything as one line and divide the separate *fields*  by some character that will play role of a delimiter in the main script on which base you can convert the string into an array. For example (where `,` is our delimiter and `-n` will suppers the newline character within `echo`):

```
echo -n "$COLOR","$exitstatus"
```

The other information that is provided by the script and is not required by the main script could be redirected to some log file:

```
$ cat whiptail.sh
```

```
#!/bin/sh
log_file='/tmp/my.log'

COLOR=$(whiptail --inputbox "What is your favorite Color?" 8 78 Blue --title "Example Dialog" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
exitstatus=$?

if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
    echo "User selected Ok and entered $COLOR" > "$log_file"
    echo -n "$COLOR","$exitstatus"
else
    echo "User selected Cancel."  >> "$log_file"
    echo -n "CANCEL","$exitstatus"
fi
```

---

Unfortunately I don't have much experience with Python, but here is a sample .py script that can handle the output of the above .sh script ([reference](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators)):

```
$ cat main-script.py
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['./whiptail.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p = p.communicate()[0]
p = p.split(",")
print "Color:    " + p[0]
print "ExitCode: " + p[1]
```

Comment: That's true even in bash I think - additionally, it's only really possible to `return` from a function or a *sourced* script (otherwise, there's no calling context to return *to*)

Comment: actually i guess i missed to add one more part in question... below is the python code from which im calling the shell script.. and i need to return the $COLOR value to python script.

#!/bin/sh

import subprocess

P = subprocess.call(['./whiptail.sh'])

print(P)

Comment: Hello, @muthukumar, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I needed the return value from a shell command in my Python script.

The `subprocess` method `check_output()` helped me get the shell return code as a byte string in the Python file.

Here is the code:

```
return_value =subprocess.check_output("sudo raspi-config nonint get_spi", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell = True)
print(return_value)


<<<b'1\n'
```